# How add new tab with links to menu (mobile version) on Magento 2?

Tags: magento-2.1, xml, phtml

[image: Example]
I create CMS block with my links and include them to `app/design/frontend/My-vendor/Name-theme/Magento_Theme/layout/default.xml`

```
    <referenceContainer name="header.panel">
        <block class="Magento\Cms\Block\Block" name="header_links_block">
            <arguments>
                <argument name="block_id" xsi:type="string">header_links_block</argument>
            </arguments>
        </block>
    </referenceContainer>
```

**What's correct way for include my link to phone style same on picture?** For have other tab "Information", and inside my links. You can see example on picture.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your theme make the file **{theme_dir}/Magento_Theme/layout/default.xml** with this contents:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="navigation.sections">
            <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="store.information" group="navigation-sections" template="Magento_Theme::html/container.phtml">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="title" translate="true" xsi:type="string">Information</argument>
                </arguments>
                <block class="Magento\Cms\Block\Block" name="information_block">
                    <arguments>
                        <argument name="block_id" xsi:type="string">header_links_block</argument>
                    </arguments>
                </block>
            </block>
        </referenceBlock>
    </body>
</page>
```

This creates a new tab in the mobile menu with the CMS block.

If your store has language options then there will now be 4 tabs and you have to change some CSS to accommodate the new tab because tab width is set to `33.33%`.